# Laravel package not autoloading - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a laravel package, but it won't autoload.

This is the autoload section of my package:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Doitonlinemedia\\Translatableroutes\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

Classes are namespaced like `Doitonlinemedia\Translatableroutes`

Folder structure is like:

```
- vendor
- - doitonlinemedia
- - - translatableroutes
- - - - composer.json
- - - - src
- - - - - class1.php
```

I've added the ServiceProvider in app.php like:
`Doitonlinemedia\Translatableroutes\TranslatableRoutesServiceProvider::class`

But it keeps saying **Class 'Doitonlinemedia\Translatableroutes\TranslatableRoutesServiceProvider' not found**

Run `composer dump-autoload` on every change.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

For development I added: `"Doitonlinemedia\\Translatableroutes\\": "packages/doitonlinemedia/translatableroutes/src"` to the main composer.json file. But when I require this composer package into a new project I'm getting the above problems.

To try out this package: https://github.com/doitonlinemedia/TranslatableRoutes and follow the instructions

Answer (score 4):

PHP namespaces are case sensitive.
You have to put this into your composer.json

```
"psr-4": {
    "Doitonlinemedia\\Translatableroutes\\": "src/"
}
```

instead of this

```
"psr-4": {
    "doitonlinemedia\\translatableroutes\\": "src/"
}
```

> For me it works also without the `classmap` option

run `composer dump-autoload` again and retry.

**Edit**

This works for me

```
{
    "name": "doitonlinemedia/translatableroutes",
    "description": "Create translatable resource routes",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Tim van Uum",
            "email": "tim@doitonlinemedia.nl"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "src"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Doitonlinemedia\\Translatableroutes\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

In addition you should add this package to your requirements `"illuminate/support": "~5.2"`.

**Note:** It seems to composer do not refresh the autoload entries of `composer.json` files located in vendor packages if they are not updated.

After editing you have to push this into your repository. Reinstall the package in your project.

If you are still developing actively on your package I recommend to setup an environment by following this instructions: [Developing your packages in Laravel 5](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/developing-your-packages-in-laravel-5).

It's so much easier to develop your package without reinstalling or updating the remote repository always.

Comment: Just noticed that. Apparently it worked already. See my answer in laracast. I'll add that package to the requirements (what does it btw?)  And I'll keep your in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help on laracast forum. I found out that my project was bit corrupt I guess, cause the package was already working.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/trouble-autoloading-custom-package-laravel-52